# Why are Methyl vibr. modes called r modes and methylene vibr. modes called d modes

Tags: spectroscopy, group-theory, ir-spectroscopy

I am coming from a chemical background and currently work in the field of vibrational spectroscopy. When I talk to fellow physicists or chemists I always encounter the same question. "Why are the vibrational modes of methyl- and methylenegroups are called r and d modes".

Does this have a group theory background? Can someone elaborate on that?

Comment: Can you show a reference/ webpage which shows r and d modes? What is the context?

Comment: [Vibrations](https://i.postimg.cc/FHV9RRxv/Screenshot-2021-03-25-at-13-17-39.png) In this picture i illustrated the methyl and methylene stretching vibrations.

Comment: Where is the reference to this picture?